In GPV08 lattice signature, why the fact that the bijective from quotient group to the set of syndromes holds?
I was recently reading the lattice-based signature scheme GPV08 (full paper), and the following statement confuses me alot (which is in the section 5.1, page 17&18):

Throughout the paper, we use two easy but important facts about the lattices defined above. First... The second fact is that the quotient group $(\mathbb{Z}^m/\Lambda^\bot)$ and the set of syndromes $\{\textbf{u}=\textbf{A}\textbf{e}\ \textsf{mod}\,q:\,\textbf{e}\in\mathbb{Z}^m\}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}^n_q$ are in bijective correspondence, via the mapping $(\textbf{e}+\Lambda^\bot)\mapsto \textbf{A}\textbf{e}\,\textsf{mod}\,q$.

where lattice $\Lambda$ is generated by matrix $\textbf{A}\in \mathbb{Z}^{n\times m}_q$ and $\Lambda^\bot$ is the q-ary lattice.
I don't understand why the fact above holds. How could the quotient group be connected with the set of syndromes?
Could anyone gives an explanation?

The first isomorphism theorem for groups (though there are analogues for most other familiar algebraic objects) states that if

$G, H$ are groups, and
$f : G\to H$ is a group homomorphism, then (among other things)

$\mathsf{im}(f) \cong G / \ker(f)$.
Note that
$$
\Lambda^\perp = \{e\in\mathbb{Z}^n\mid Ae\equiv 0 \bmod q\}
$$
is precisely $\ker(f)$ for $f : \mathbb{Z}^n\to \mathbb{Z}_q^n$ defined by $f(x) = Ax\bmod q$.
It is easy to see that your set of syndromes is precisely $\mathsf{im}(f)$.
By the aformentioned isomorphism theorem, we then get that
$$
G / \ker(f) = \mathbb{Z}^n / \Lambda^\perp\cong \mathsf{im}(f).
$$
This is to say it all really just follows from standard group theory.
You could try to think about this more concretely if you want to though. How would you represent an element of $\mathbb{Z}^n / \Lambda^\perp$?
Think about this for an easier quotient group first --- namely $\mathbb{Z}^n / q\mathbb{Z}^n$.
Here, we write a representative of the quotient group as an element of $\mathbb{Z}^n$.
We might try to define some "reduction procedure" where we add elements of $q\mathbb{Z}^n$ to this representative to try to find some distinguished representative (typically with coefficients in some set like $[0, q)^n$ or something).
You can do this same thing for $\mathbb{Z}^n / \Lambda^\perp$.
It is less obvious what the reduction procedure would be, but what is obvious is that you would have an integer vector representative $\vec x\in\mathbb{Z}^n$, and would add elements of $\Lambda^\perp$ to try to find some distinguished representative.
These elements of $\Lambda^\perp$ are all integer vectors $e$ with $Ae\equiv 0\bmod q$.
So $\vec x+e$ would all be equivalent for any such $e$ (they are the entire equivalence class of $x\in\mathbb{Z}^n / \Lambda^\perp$).
We might then wonder what happens if we look at the image of this equivalence class under the mapping $x\mapsto Ax\bmod q$.
We will get $A(x+e)\bmod q\equiv Ax\bmod q$, e.g. our equivalence class will be sent to precisely a syndrome. This proves that $\mathbb{Z}^n / \Lambda^\perp$ is a subgroup of the set of all syndromes. To prove it is the whole group, note that we can reverse the process. Namely, the set of syndromes are the set of vectors $u\in\mathbb{Z}_q^n$ such that there exists $x\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ with $Ax\bmod q\equiv u$.
So the aformentioned mapping is invertible, and the groups are isomorphic.
